# How to get an actual copy of my eOs configuration in an executable penrdive?

Tags: release-hera, usb-drive

Does anyone knows how to get my current elementary OS 5.1 Hera configuration  to work in an executable usb pendrive?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Pinguy Builder (https://pinguyos.com/2018/05/pinguy-builder-updated-license-change/) for that exact purpose. While it works nicely, it does has some limitations on the SquashFS size so if your installation is too big, you might not be able to build a working Live Environment.

If that doesn't work, you might Google around for " install linux ubuntu on USB drive". Never attempted that myself though.